# How do I show a list of running processes on macos?

Tags: macos, terminal, ps

I want to close a lot of programs at once using `killall`, and make a batch list in time.

I assume I'd run one of:

- ps -ax (just what's showing in the CMD column)
- lsof  (just show process name)

Then, using for example grep sed awk or whatever, I'd like a list of processes names (with quotes at start and end) I can hand to killall for closing in bulk, piped in with xargs or from a text file.

BEFORE: example

```
2138 ttys003    0:00.29 ssh -Y root@cheese
 4594 ttys006    0:00.05 login -pf tom
 4685 ??         0:07.70 /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/71.0.3578.98/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper --type=renderer
  771 ??        11:24.08 /Applications/Utilities/System Information.app/Contents/MacOS/System Information
```

AFTER:

```
"ssh"
"login"
"Google Chrome Helper"
"System Information"
```

Each line should work in killall, for example:

killall "System Information"

Something like:

```
ps -ax | grep -E "([0-9]* .* [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9] )(.*) (--)"
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you want, to me it looks like you’ve answered the question in the title yourself.

Comment: i've added an example with grep that uses 3 capture groups to try to show im trying to cut out the process name using a regular expression, but the goal is just a list of process names in the terminal i can cherry-pick to hand off to the killall command.